# How to use aggregate function with a case statement and a where condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get max(level) and sum(hours) until someone reaches level 5 for the first time.
This is my input

| date | level | hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 1/2/2021 | 2 | 1 |
| 1/3/2021 | 2 | 2 |
| 1/4/2021 | 3 | 1 |
| 1/5/2021 | 4 | 1 |
| 1/6/2021 | 5 | 3 |
| 1/7/2021 | 5 | 1 |
| 1/8/2021 | 5 | 1 |

Output before the aggregate

| date | level | hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 1/2/2021 | 2 | 1 |
| 1/3/2021 | 2 | 2 |
| 1/4/2021 | 3 | 1 |
| 1/5/2021 | 4 | 1 |
| 1/6/2021 | 5 | 3 |

Final output

select max(level) as level, sum(hours) as total_hours
from final

| level | hours |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 9 |

I am not sure how to use case statement with sum where I wanted to limit my data when it reached level 5 for the first time

This should calculate sum of hours if level is less than 5 as well

Comment: What do you mean "for the first time"? Are you trying to find out what level they were when their cumulative total over time reached at least 5?

Comment: I am trying to find out their cumulative hours, But when level 5 is reached I want to sum up only till 1/6/2021 and not beyond that.  How long it took to reach level 5 - Calculation should be from level 1 till level 5 for the first time

Comment: What do you mean "their" hours? There is no "person_id" column. It seems there is only data for one person here.

Comment: yes there are multiple person here, but I am trying to limit to one person's data

Comment: MySql supports window functions since 8.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(level) AS level,
       SUM(CASE WHEN date >= (SELECT MIN(date) FROM input WHERE level = 5)
                THEN 0 ELSE hours END) AS total_hours
FROM input;
```

- finds the earliest date when level is equal to 5.
- CASE  limits SUM of hours to 0 for all rows with a date greater than or equal to this earliest date, stopping the sum when level 5 is reached for the first time
- MAX function finds the maximum level value in the table

Comment: do you have a sql fiddle with a working demo

Comment: @user62367 is there some reason you cannot test this yourself? Or are you hinting that the solution does not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your table has `id` column, here is the query:

```
SELECT MAX(level), SUM(hours) FROM table_name
WHERE id <= (SELECT MIN(id) FROM table_name WHERE level = 5);
```

Condition `id <= (SELECT MIN(id) FROM table_name WHERE level = 5)` will restrict your data to a record where it reached level 5 for the first time

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

`SELECT MAX(level), SUM(hours)  FROM Table1 WHERE date <= (SELECT MIN(date) FROM Table1 WHERE level = 5 limit 1)`;

- Minimum DATE required with Minumum Level = 5

`SELECT MAX(level), SUM(hours)  FROM Table1  WHERE date <=  (SELECT MIN(date) FROM Table1 WHERE level = 5 limit 1) or date <= (SELECT MAX(date) FROM Table1 WHERE level < 5)`

And - Maximum DATE required with Level < 5

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e35e77/52)

Comment: This doesn't work if level is less than 5 - Say when we have only 4 levels - the sum of hours should be until level 4

Comment: mention about level -4 in your question

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query this will works..

```
select max(level) Level,sum(hours) Hours from Table1 where date <= 
(select max(date) from Table1 where hours = (select Max(hours) from Table1))
```

[Result](https://dbfiddle.uk/MUaeciGv)

Edited: If if the same hours occurred, then it will take the exact sum.